# Detect DOM changes generated outside of my Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that is injecting an iFrame into the dom after a page loads.

I also want listen for dom changes but I want to ignore a the `DOMSubtreeModified` that was fired as a result of me injecting the iFrame. So any event, before or after I've injected my iFrame, I want to capture.

Here's the basics of my content script that is looking at dom changes:

```
var processRequest = function() {
  $('body').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', DOMModificationHandler);
  return 'complete';
}

function DOMModificationHandler() {
  $(this).unbind('DOMSubtreeModified');
  setTimeout(function() {
    //skip this if it was my iFrame injection that caused this event
    //someLocalFunction();
    $('#ContentContainer').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', DOMModificationHandler);
  },1000);
}
```

Is there something I can do to differentiate between my injection, and other dom events, when the `DOMModificationHandler` fires?

**Update: I considered adding some type of id or data element to the iFrame but that just tells me that it's there, not that it was the iFrame that caused the event. Especially when there is an AJAX request that has updated part of the dom. Any id or data attribute will probably already exist so I still wont know the source of the dome change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified and subsequently http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-target.  You should be able to filter events based on their target.  In this case the target is the parent subtree being modified.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I added an event arg to the DOMModificationHandler function. From there, I test for e.target.id if one exists. This enables me to filter events the way I need. Thanks!